# Basic string formatting in Rails view using loops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, loops

Hi newb to Rails here.

I want to format a string to fit into an html div. The model I'm after is;

- Break the string into an array seperated by whitespace.
- If any array item length is greater than 22
- Split the characters into lengths of 22 and display.
- else separate the words by whitespace and then display.

It's for handling long names on a guestbook type application.

```
    <% $p = 0 %>
    <% @m = name.split(" ") %>
      <% while $p < @m.size do %>
        <% if @m[$p].length > 22 %>
          <%= name.slice(0, 21) %><br>
          <%= name.slice(21, 43) %><br>
            <% else %>
          <% $i = 0 %>
          <% @x = name.split(" ") %>
            <% while $i < @x.size do %>
              <%= @x[$i] %><br>
              <% $i +=1 %>
            <% end %>
        <% end  %>
      <% $p +=1 %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have a collection of names?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's for passing full usernames to a stylized view from a db table.

Comment: Being that you're new to using ERB... Don't put logic like this into your view/template. It should be performed prior to the templater being called, so all that has to be done is an array or hash walked and the values output. In Rails, that means your logic would be in your controller, not the view. Also, you're using globals (`$p`, `$i`) and creating instance variables (`@m`, `@x`) which hints that you don't understand variable scoping.

Comment: @the Tin Man - I have a lot to learn, and that is valuable advice, my friend. I'll need to go through some decent ERB practice tutorials I guess. Cheers.

Comment: Personally, I'd highly recommend skipping learning ERB and go right to using [Haml](http://haml.info). It's easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(1..(name.length / 22)).each { |i| name[22*i] = ' ' } if name.length > 22
```

Comment: @Peet If the length is > 22, it just uses a range to iterate over how many "chunks" there should be. i is the loop count, it takes that time 22 and sticks a space in.